# How can i replace path with file name?

Tags: c#, file, datagridview, path, resources

Hello i have to finish school project after another student.
And in whole program he used absolute path to file, the problem is it only works at one computer. Cuz this path is unique. 
Could anybody tell me how can i replace this path just with file name?

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            this.DocumentXml = XDocument.Parse(content);
            this.xmlInfo = XDocument.Parse(content);
            var groups = this.DocumentXml.Root.Elements("group");

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(group.Attribute("name").Value);
            }
            // Adding data from your DNSFile to dataGridView1

            hostsDataSet.Clear();
            hostsDataSet.ReadXml(filePath);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = hostsDataSet;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "item";
```

In this case "filepath" is text file with absolute path with file that he used.
Can you help me?

This is whole path to the file, that i create with `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath`: **C:\Users\praktykant1\AppData\Local\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\1.0.0.0\test.txt**

Problem in my case is that i have to create file that i use in program in AppData/Local folder.So on every computer the path will be different. And this program must work on every computer. Im just beginner so i am green in this subject.

Comment: Look at the `System.IO.Path` class. It has several static methods that could help you...

Comment: Use config file to store path and retrieve the path value from config, so that you can easily change the path.

Comment: use google and you can start here [Path.GetFileName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) also since filePath is a text file with absolute path why not show us the path as well is

Comment: Thank you MethoMan, that helped...

Comment: what you are wanting to do is not that difficult so help yourself to google also do not hard code filepaths this is what .config file have been designed for any and all settings that you want your application to read from start storing them inside a .config file

Answer (score 1):

This is precisely what config files are for... differences between environments in which the same code might execute.

Presumably the problem is that `filePath` is hard-coded, yes?  Something like this?:

```
var filePath = @"c:\some\path\to\a\file.xml";
```

Instead, make that a configuration value.  First add an entry to the `App.config` (or `Web.config` if this is a web application) in the `appSettings` node:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="filePath" value="c:\some\path\to\a\file.xml" />
    <!-- any other settings already in place... -->
</appSettings>
```

Then use `ConfigurationManager` to get that setting.  (You may need to add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly in the project.)  Something like this:

```
var filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
```

You might also perform some error checking to make sure there's a value there at all (make sure `filePath` doesn't end up as a null or empty string, that is), make sure the file exists, etc.

At this point you can change the value in the config file without having to re-compile the code.  So any new environment can set the config setting and use the application.

Answer (score 1):

To get the file name of a path, just do this.
For example if your path is "C:\hello.txt", it becomes "hello.txt"

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
```

If you do not like your file name to have any extensions

```
string fileNameNoEx = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

That way it becomes "hello"

Answer (score 0):

If you set the variable `filepath` to be just the filename  - it would look for this file in the directory where the executable file was started from (by default). This is called the *working directory* and you can find how to change the working directory [online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want to avoid using a full (or relative) path and just use the filename - expect it to be in that working directory.

Answer (score 0):

In case of ASP.net you can do this,

```
      if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
      {
          try
          {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
          }
     }
```